# Jquery rotate not working

Tags: jquery

I have a little button which i want to rotate when i click on it.
I tried the most direct way, which in my opinion is:

`$(this).rotate(45);`

This is the way it looks in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(function() {
        $('.fa-plus-circle').click(function() {    
            $(this).rotate(45);   
        });
    });
});
```

I went to my browser and opened the console and this is what i saw there:

[image: console error]

I tried changing the jquery library from the latest to 1.7.2, that didn't work either. I tried using something different after, I used

`$(this)slideUp`

And yup, that worked for some reason. It seems to have trouble with "rotate".

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

https://jsfiddle.net/exm8gkbd/

Comment: Why do you think that `rotate()` is a jquery function? Have you got any plugin that creates it? `I tried the most direct way, which in my opinion is...` what kind of opinion is this without reading the manual?

Comment: Try this plugin: http://jqueryrotate.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Anatol/T6kDR/ I saw this here hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method like `rotate()` in jQuery. You need to use **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method to apply `transform`.

```
$(this).css('transform','rotate(45deg)');
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I saw this here.. http://jsfiddle.net/Anatol/T6kDR/ so i thought that was the way to go.

Comment: Scroll down in the JavaScript view to line 51. You see there the jQuery Rotate plugin made by anatol.at :D.

Comment: I know, my reaction was meant for @Madses. Should have used the `@Madses` tag...

Comment: Aha, well kind of stupid from my part assuming it was a function! But thanks for the help! @JacobvanLingen